# Como desabilitar HTTPS no CentOS Apache 2 instalado no Amazon EC2?

Tags: ssl, certificado-digital, https, centos

Instalei o CentOS uma instancia Amazon EC2, e inseri um certificado SSL usando [*Let's Encrypt - Free SSL/TLS Certificates*](https://letsencrypt.org/). Foi tudo bonitinho e está funcionando perfeitamente. Vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Toda vez que é inserido `http://`, automaticamente o usuário é redirecionado para `https://`. Como estou realizando alguns testes, gostaria de desabilitar o HTTPS.

Entrei no arquivo `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` e vi toda configuração, porém não soube o que fazer para desabilitar o HTTPS para que volte a funcionar somente usando HTTP.

Como posso desabilitar HTTPS no CentOS Apache 2 instalado no Amazon EC2?

Comment: Você quer desabilitar o HTTPS ou quer desabilitar apenas o redirecionamento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o que você quer é apenas desabilitar o redirecionamento, basta procurar no `httpd.conf` (ou arquivos incluídos de configuração) algo semelhante a isto:

```
Redirect permanent / https://dominio.com/
```

> É bem provavel que esteja nos vhosts

Pode ser que o redirecionamento esteja em um `.htaccess` também, pode ser algo semelhante a isto:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://dominio/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Basta adicionar `#` na frente pra comentar esta linha.

É **importante** lembrar que quando o navegador recebe um redirecionamento 301 mesmo que você remova o redirecionamento o navegador ainda continuará direcionando para a url com HTTPS, isso porque o redirecionamento 301 é chamado de redirecionamento permanente e com isto o navegador grava nos seus dados locais do seu perfil o tal redirecionamento, ou seja o navegador antes mesmo de você conseguir conectar no dominio irá redirecionar para o HTTPS.

Para evitar esse redirecionamento só existem duas maneiras, limpando os dados de navegação ou abrindo em modo anonimo o navegador.

Comment: Estou dando um http:// pelo Postman e está dando 404 Page Not Found.

Comment: @white teu virtualhost deve estar configurado somente para HTTPS, posta os virtualhosts para eu ver por favor.

Comment: Engraçado, entrei em /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf porém não tem virtualhost lá. Acredito que depois que instalei o lets encrypt, passou a usar somente https.

Comment: no ssl.conf tem o <virtualhost *.443> somente.

Comment: Mano, valeu memo!!! Não tinha o virtualhost mesmo no httpd.conf, somente no ssl.conf... ai oque eu fiz, fui lá e criei um VirtualHost manual no httpd.conf  foi de boa. agora esta funcionando tanto http quanto https;

Comment: Acredito que com a configuração do lets encrypt, de alguma forma excluiu a opção de navegação porta 80. Vou ler mais um pouco pra ver o que pode ter acontecido.

Comment: Tem algo que estou boiano aqui

Comment: Mas fora do ssl.conf existem outros virtualhost? Sem porta alguma? Procure tudo aonde estiver escrito algo como `DocumentRoot ...`, deve existir em mais de um lugar ... se existir apenas no 443, então procure outros virtualhost, independente do que esta dentro do ssl.conf. Ao encontrar veja se ele contem `DocumentRoot` e veja para onde ele esta apontando @white

Comment: @white essa instalação do SSL geralmente não muda o que já existe, foi manualmente que fez isso?

Comment: O problema era mesmo o redirecionamento. Quando eu fazia uma requisição, estava dando 404.. Ai fiz o que você disse, removi o redirecionamento e funcionou. Depois eu vou alterar isso pra que funcione mesmo somente com ssl... é que no momento não posso porque teria que atualizar o app que está apontando para o http e não https. Assim que eu enviar uma nova atualização do app, eu ativo o redirecionamento novamente. Vlw pela ajuda.